# Accessing Spring Boot configuration properties from logback-spring.groovy

Tags: spring, groovy, logback

I have been looking for a way to access the Spring Boot configuration properties (from `application.yml`) in my `logback-spring.groovy` config file.

According to the documentation this is [possible from the XML config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_environment_properties), but I am struggling to see how to do it in the groovy DSL config.

The simple `${some.property}` substitution doesn't work.

EDIT:
I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801691/how-to-get-environment-properties-from-application-properties-into-logback-groov), it has some tips on possible approaches, but not a definitive answer. So far it looks like it is not possible to do what I am asking for in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have to parse the YAML file yourself, since the `logback-spring.groovy` script is evaluated very early in the bootstrap process.

Can you work with Java System Properties?